# How to pass variable from javascript file to server to ejs template

Tags: javascript, ejs

In my project I want the user to select a radio button,  then based on the value of the radio button I want to display a unique page. I have to use an ejs template and I don't understand how to pass the value of the button to the ejs template.

```
<input name="imagePick" value="1" type="radio" id="one">
<label for="one">
   <img src="images/aries.png" alt="aries" height="150" width="auto">
</label>

<input name="imagePick" value="2" type="radio" id="two">
<label for="two">
    <img src="images/taurus.png" alt="taurus" height="150" width="auto">
</label>
```

```
$("input[name='imagePick']").on("change", function() {
    var sign = $('input[name="imagePick"]:checked').val();
    console.log("the sign is: " + sign);
});
```

var theSign = sign;

res.render('template.ejs', {theSign : theSign});

```
</head>
    <body>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < allTheData.length; i++) { %>
        <h1>Hi <span id="first"><%=allTheData[i].first%></span><br/><br/></h1>
        <% } %>

        <h1> sign: <span id="sign"><%=theSign%></span></h1><br/> 
        <h2> what a great webapp </h2> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the form is part of the client-side DOM and the EJS is being converted to HTML by server-side code: You need to send the data to the server in an HTTP request.

Put the form controls in a `<form>`, set the `action` to a URL handled by a route in your Express code, then read it from the query string or request body depending on if you chose to use [GET or POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get). Process the data however you like, and then pass it in [an object as the argument to `render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to pass values to other page. One of them is making a GET request submitting form fields:

```
<!-- view1.ejs -->
<form method="get" action="someRoute">
    <input name="imagePick" value="1" type="radio" id="one">
    <input name="imagePick" value="2" type="radio" id="two">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Map the form route ("someRoute") and get submitted values:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('someRoute', function (req, res) {
    var radioButtonVal = req.query.imagePick;
    res.render('myView', { myData: radioButtonVal /* <<< passing received data to view */ });
});
```

Render view:

```
<!-- view2.ejs -->
<body>
    <% if (myData == "1") { %>
        <div></div>
    <% } else if (myData == "2") { %>
        <div></div>
    <% } else { %>
        <div></div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```